# How do you make line segments between two points and find out how many points intersect the line?

Tags: python

I have code that generates all the possible lines between points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
import itertools 

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
all_data = [[1,10],[2,10],[3,10],[4,10],[5,10],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5]]
x, y = zip(*all_data)
plt.scatter(x,y)
for pair in itertools.combinations(all_data,2):
    line=lines.Line2D(*zip(*pair))
    line.set_color('brown')
    ax.add_line(line)

plt.show()
```

[image]

but I want how many points each line intersects. (points are blue)

Comment: Are you trying to get the two best fitting lines? Try RANSAC (i.e pick two random points, get line through them, throw out all points with more than 1.0 distance from line, do regression fitting. )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (untested):

```
def crossf(p1, p2):
  u"returns a boolean function for testing line (p1, p2)"
  if p1[0] == p2[0]:
    y = [p1[1], p2[1]]
    y.sort()
    # if p3 falls within the y range it is on the line
    return lambda p3: (p3[1] >= y[0]) and (p3[1] <= y[1])
  else:
    slope = p2[1] - p1[1], p2[0] - p1[0]
    # y/x ratio of point (p3 - p1) must equal slope
    return lambda p3: (p3[0] - p1[0]) * slope[1] == (p3[1] - p1[1]) * slope[0]

crosstests = dict([(pair, crossf(*pair) for pair in itertools.combinations(all_data,2)])

for pair in crosstests:
  for point in all_data:
    print 'point %s does %sfall on line %s' % (point, 
        '' if crosstests[pair](point) else 'not ', pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this distance metric. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html
It has a nice vector expression towards the end. Permute all point-line combinations, if d is less than epsilon, you have an intersection.